# Is while loop poorly optimized in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, while-loop

I know this question has already been asked multiple times,  but my teacher is saying that in Java you should (almost) never  use the while loop and use instead the for loop.

So, I haven't find anything that goes in this way.
Maybe she saw some kind of Internet nonsense  or maybe, long time ago in an old version.

Has the `while` loop (or has had in some old version) any issues that makes the `for` loop more efficient?

Comment: I have never heard about such thing before

Comment: java 8 still has it, so i dont think is broken or lazy developed....

Comment: Use of for or while loop totally depends on use case to use case. There nothing like for is better than while.

Comment: She's is wrong. `While loop` and `for loop` are two different loops and should be used according to your need. No such thing as poorly optimized `while loop`

Comment: so you should rather write `for(;not_found;)` instead of `while(not_found)` just to get a potentional 0.0000001 ms performance, if there is even a difference, which i doubt. I´d tell her to grant you a source that supports the claim or ignore it as it looks like nonsense.

Comment: Seems to be nonsense to me. How did she argument it?

Comment: Does she gave any examples?

Comment: Are you sure you did not misunderstand your teacher? You said it yourself, "my teacher is saying that in Java you should (**almost**) never use the while loop". Which implies that your teacher says it is ok to use the `while` loop. And isn't that true? If you know the number of iterations you use a `for` loop, and otherwise a `while` loop. I feel that maybe the teacher was just perhaps expressing it a little badly.

Comment: I think your teacher just said that "java enhanced for loop" must to be preferred over a "java while loop" (based on a condition, like Iterator.hasNext() ). That's true due to the readability, use of Generics and easy to avoid infinite loop. "While" loop can be used as you wish, just try to avoid to Iterate over a group (like Collection etc) of Objects

Comment: Thank you for your answers, she even says to use a for to iter (with hasNext) instead of a while. I will pick an answer to close the question.